# Permission denied message when attempting ssh to Vagrant public network IP from second machine on same network

Tags: networking, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox, remote-access

I've combed the Internet clean for this one and still can't figure it out. I have a Vagrant VM running using VirtualBox, with the following Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
     config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
     config.vm.network "public_network"

     config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
          vb.memory = "1024"
          vb.gui = true
     end
end
```

Vagrant launches successfully, and I can run `vagrant ssh` successfully and get into the box. I can view the IP of the Vagrant public network, and I'm successfully hosting two Nginx sites in the box, which I can view from a different computer on the same network by visiting the IP of the Vagrant public network.

My server is a clunky laptop, so I want to ssh directly into the Vagrant box that's running on it (from a different development machine). I specifically want to edit the files on the server remotely using the VS Code remote dev tool. I can't for the life of me figure out why, when I run

```
ssh vagrant@[IP of Vagrant public network on the server]
```

it gives me "Permission denied (publickey)." It throws this both when I try to run it on the server itself and from another machine on the network.

Do I need to modify some ssh config file somewhere?

EDIT: I read [this](https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/connecting-vagrant-box-without-vagrant-ssh-command) article, which recommended adding something like this to the ssh config file on the client machine:

```
    Host 192.168.100.100 <- Vagrant box network IP
      StrictHostKeyChecking no
      UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
      IdentitiesOnly yes
      User vagrant
      IdentityFile /your/user/directory/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
      PasswordAuthentication no
```

this didn't work for me; instead of throwing "Permission denied," it just hangs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed a copy of the private key from my [working dir]/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key file on my server. Once I scp'd that onto my secondary machine, I passed it to ssh as the IdentityFile:

```
ssh -I [location of copied private_key file] vagrant@[IP of Vagrant public network on the server]
```

and it worked.